# fork() execution in for loop

Tags: c, linux, fork

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 2) {
        fork();
        system("ps -o pid,ppid,comm,stat");
        i++;
     }
     return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Can anyone tell me how many times ps command is executed with an explanation?

Comment: Run it and find out?

Comment: yea i just wanted someone to explain me y im getting 6 -_-

Comment: Its not that bad a question,
The OP might've been confused at the strange answer at first,
Fork isn't that easy to grasp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the answer is 6.

in the first iteration, `fork()` is called, splitting the process in 2, thus calling ps twice.

in the second iteration, fork is called again in each process, so you now have 4 processes running ps.

total calls to ps: 2+4=6.

Answer (score 4):

6 times.

It creates a process tree like this:

```
A-+
  |-B-+
  |   |-C-+
  |-D
```

A does it twice (i=0)

B does it twice (i=0)

C does it once  (i=1)

D does it once  (i=1)

Note that my usage of letters is to distinguish them. There's no predictable output ordering since process switching is non-deterministic to the eyes of a programmer.

Comment: Well spotted. I hope the OP gets a good grade in his assignment ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
Initial Process
i == 0
-> Fork 1
   system call
   i == 1
   -> Fork 1.1
      system call
   system call
system call
i == 1
-> Fork 2
   system call
system call
```

I count 6, 2 each from the initial process and the first fork (4), and one from each process forked when i == 1 from those 2 processes.

Of course that's assuming you fix the missing end brace (and define EXIT_SUCCESS), otherwise none, since it won't compile. :-)